# Does before_action in class override actions defined in concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, activesupport-concern

When using concerns in Rails controllers how do filters added via before_action operate?  Specifically, if I have the following code for which actions in FeedsController will the before_action set_record run?  All of them once (show, update, destroy, foobar), all of them once and twice before destroy or only before destroy, foobar (I presume authenticate still runs only before destroy)?

```
module JsonApiController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :authenticate, only %i[ destroy ]
    before_action :set_record, only: %i[ show update destroy ]
  end

 def show/update/destroy  
 end

 protected

 def set_record
  @record = controller_path.classify.constantize.find(params[:id])
 end

end

class FeedsController < ApplicationController
  include JsonApiController

  before_action :set_record, only: %i[destroy, foobar]

  def foobar
   ...
  end

end
```

I'd like FeedsController to be able to add the set_record filter before any actions it wants without having to know what the JsonApiController did.  So, ideally, the filter :set_record would execute once before each of show/update/destroy/foobar but I don't think that's what the code below accomplishes.  But more than any particular solution I want to know how before_action works with concerns and included do so I minimize code duplication between concerns and classes.

If this was just inheritance then I know that before_actions are inherited.  But [this discussion](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/20687) suggests that a before_action in an included do in a module will be overwritten by one in the class but when I try to look at the source it suggests that append_callback is the default action so I'm confused.

Comment: What do you actually try to achieve? Do you want to run that before_action on `%i[show update destroy]`, `%i[destroy foobar]` (Note you need to remove the comma when using this array syntax), or `%i[show update destroy foobar]`?

Comment: What I want to achieve is to run the before_action on %i[ show update destroy, foobar ] once (I only repeated the destroy before_action in class in the hope of figuring out general case).

In particular, I want to define my concern in such a way that the classes that include it can add their own before_actions to their own methods without having to worry about overwriting/undoing filters from the concern.

Comment: What I would do is put some debug printing in and execute a few requests to see exactly when and how many times this callback is executed. I'd probably do that even before diving head first into the source code (those trips can be long and not always fruitful)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, but I kinda had a guess at what would happen here and I'm trying to understand enough to know how to create the filters correctly so I don't need to repeat all of them to add another method to the filter.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Rails Guides: Action Controller Overview/Filters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters):

> Calling the same filter multiple times with different options will not work, since the last filter definition will overwrite the previous ones.

That said if you want to change or update the configuration of a `before_action` then that new config will override all existing filters with the same method name.

Therefore, in your example, you will need to use the following new declaration to extend (actually override) the existing declaration from the included module:

```
before_action :set_record, only: %i[show update destroy foobar]
```

Comment: Is that true in a super class as well or does that count as a 'different' filter?
I mean I saw that statement but it doesn't really help since for all I know filters defined in different scopes aren't the 'same' filter and I wasn't even totally sure for concerns.

Comment: Also does  'same filter' mean each call to before_action with the same first argument? (Regardless of where in inheritance hierarchy??) So if I added an alias in the class it wouldn't conflict?  I'm looking for the right way to do this so I don't need to repeat filters in the class that it should leave to the concern to handle.

Comment: @PeterGerdes The [`current implementation`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L661) looks like working with aliases might work. But that behavior is not explicitly documented and might change. I would not depend on that bebavior.

Comment: Thank you, ... sorry but I'm digging through the callbacks code and I'm still having trouble figuring out if I run before_action :set_record in both ApplicationController and FeedsController (which inherits) do those also override each other or not?

Comment: The code in the ApplicationController is never "run" because the code in it is never called directly. What happens instead is that the code is called in the context of the FeedsController and therefore only code in the FeedsContoller is run which sometimes might be implemented in a mixin or an inherit Controller.

Comment: Why don't you build a simple test, for example, with some example output to the log file and test what happens? That is certainly easier than reading the Rails source code for callbacks and filters.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the other answers, Rails will only honor the last call of `before_action` for any given method. If you still want to keep the action in the concern, you work around by specifying a block. Example:

```rb
before_action(only: %i[destroy, foobar]) { set_record }
```